# How to write my query in Relational Algebra?

Tags: relational-algebra

I have a dataset which has files of hotel reviews. Each file contains multiple reviews for a single hotel. Here are my two relations in BCNF:

1. Hotel(hotelID, OverallRating, AveragePrice, URL)
2. Review(hotelID, Author, Content, Date, No. Reader, No. Helpful,
   Overall, Value, Rooms, Location, Cleanliness, Checkin / front desk,
   Service, Business Service)

I am trying to write the following query in relational algebra:

```
Find all the reviews by the same user (i.e., given a user ID, return the list of all their 
reviews).
```

By User ID, the question is referring to the Author attribute found in my second relation. The way I understand the question, it must take a user ID as an argument. Maybe you see it differently?

Here is what I have so far:

```
(Selection) Author = $1 (Review)
```

Replace selection with the sigma symbol used to represent selection in relational algebra, I was having trouble inserting it into my question. $1 represents where it would take the user ID argument, this is just to show my thinking, I do not think its correct.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query will be:

σ(Author="Your_User Id") ( Hotel Join(X)(Hotel.hotelID=Review.hotelID) Review )

Where

```
 σ = Selection Operator

  X= Join Operator

  (-----) = Condition
```

Hope it helps. For More detail Refer My notes for DBMS: [Relational Algebra](http://ashishparihargatenotes.blogspot.in/2016/03/database-management-system-best-one.html)
Search "Relational Algebra" Term in site to find your exact information fast.